# Get linkedin Access Token with JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, access-token

I am working on that application allow user to connect to linkedin (using javascript). I want to store access token that I got from IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token because I will use it to post to user's timeline.

But when I use this access token to post to Linkedin, I got "Invalid access token" error.
Did I use correct access token? How's the correct way to get Access token?

Here's my code:

```
$("#linkedin-connect").on('click',function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    IN.UI.Authorize().place();
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", OnLinkedInAuth);  
    return false;
});

function OnLinkedInAuth() {
    console.debug("oauth token:" + IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rsakura/osar4po0/)**

Comment: Did you get that token from an [OAuth authentication](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) using the [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)?

Comment: I followed the instructions here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk.  On the callback function I captured  IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token; If its not the correct acces token, how's the correct way to get it?

Comment: Please show us the code you used to get the IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token.

Comment: I put the code here http://jsfiddle.net/rsakura/osar4po0/. Thanks,  really appreciate your help.

Comment: So it looks like there is no answers ?

Comment: Where do yo do the POST request? It may be that you are using an OAuth 1 token and it needs an OAuth 2 token.

If you do it from the library itself, it may be that your token has expired and you need to call refresh method to refresh the token.

Comment: Its a guess - I think when using javascript SDK it gives an oauth token with short expiry time and its not permanent. If you are using a backend code to get the oauth token it might be a permanent token.

Comment: The oauth tokens you get via JS api cannot be used server-side. I have debugged how JS uses them and they are passed via "oauth_token: ..." HTTP header instead of the "Authorization: Bearer ...". However when you try it that way from your server-side you will get the error "[unauthorized]. IP Address Mismatch" back from LinkedIn. Apparently they link the client IP address with the oauth token. Honestly I think the JS API is completely useless like this because if you can't verify/use the token server-side you basically cannot trust any of the information.

Comment: @Arthur have you find any solution to this as I am also struggling with same issue

Comment: @vinitpayal I ended up using their REST API instead

Answer (score 1):

this event `IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", OnLinkedInAuth);` should pass some data to your function `OnLikedInAuth` as in shown in the documentation of the sdk.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
}

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
```

As that example (available in docs) the `getProfileData` (similar to your `OnLinkedInAuth`) returns a Promise and when it's resolved will give you some `data` that you need to read. In that object you will find the token that you can store (LocalStorage) and use