# Retrieve Access Token with LinkedIn JS SDK to use in Back-end

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Currently I have both Facebook and LinkedIn Oauth2 flow working fine. Because in some cases I don't want the user to redirect to another page, I use the Facebook JS SDK that works fine, retrieving the access token and sending it to the server where I retrieve user data with REST calls.

Unfortunately, I'm not having success in doing the same with the LinkedIn JS SDK. The official documentation isn't helpful at all in that regard: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk.

I retrieve user data in the server because it's easy to forge fake data in the client side and send it to the server, so a client side solution for that is not an option.

If I try to use the token that I get in js in the REST API I get `Invalid access token.` (401)

There are several opened questions that doesn't have any response (or a helpful response) here in SO:

2015-08-03 - No response:
[Javascript: Linkedin Access TOken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778193/javascript-linkedin-access-token)

2016-05-29 - No response:
[can I get access token through LinknedIn JS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509948/can-i-get-access-token-through-linknedin-js-sdk)

2016-08-31 - No helpful response (data is retrieved in the front-end):
[How to Get Access Token Using LinkedIn API JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248457/how-to-get-access-token-using-linkedin-api-javascript-sdk)

2017-06-30 - No helpful response:
[LinkedIn OAuth token with Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841919/linkedin-oauth-token-with-javascript-sdk)

---

In the below question, there is a comment that says what I'm already guessing:

> [...] Honestly I think the JS API is completely useless like this
>   because if you can't verify/use the token server-side you basically
>   cannot trust any of the information.

2015-07-22 - No helpful response (data is retrieved in the front-end):
[get linkedin Access Token with JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553463/get-linkedin-access-token-with-javascript-sdk)

---

There's some information about exchanging the Javascript API tokens with a REST API OAuth token, but in the references I've found the links are broken (and it would be impractical to do this, depending on the complexity, instead of using the token directly, like in the Facebook JS SDK):

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens
https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

---

So, I would like to know if **there is some way to login with LinkedIn using the JS SDK and retrieve the user data in the back-end using REST calls** (like I do in the Oauth2 flow), hopefully with official docs.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get past this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @justADreamer See the answer that I marked as accepted (from @dbeja). Instead of calling `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~[...]?oauth2_access_token=[token]&format=json`, I now call it passing the oauth token in the header `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~[...]?format=json` + `Headers { 'oauth_token': [token] }`.

Comment: Yeah. But I still need to get the access token somehow because my backend is heavily dependent on using an long lived access token :-| I think there's no way for me to exchange my oauth token with an access token.

Comment: @justADreamer in my case I only use the token to retrieve the user data (especially the id and the email), because these are important data that shouldn't be passed from the front-end directly. I don't need long lived tokens in my use case, and I haven't used them (unless I used without knowing they were long lived :P), so I really can't help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and the only way I found to use the JS token was to add the header oauth_token instead of an Authorization Bearer header:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,picture-url,email-address)?format=json
Headers {
  'oauth_token': JS_TOKEN
}
```

The JS_TOKEN I'm reading on frontend from **IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token**.

Comment: Thanks, @dbeja. Unfortunately I still could not login, although at least now the error is different. I'm having now `[unauthorized]. Expired access token. Timestamp: 1451220123987` (401). The timestamp seems to be from 2015. I don't think the access token is (or should be) old because every time I reload the page I get a new one, the expires field is 1800 (I think in seconds, so 30min?), but even so I'm always getting this response. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it! When I called `IN.init(...)` I was passing `authorize: true`. I think it was using some old cookie or something like that (weird that the access token was different for each request). I removed this field and it worked. Thanks @dbeja!

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue for some time, this is the way I solved it (not using the JS SDK): [image: Linkedin data flow]

Step 1: you send your user to the LinkedIn login page, in the redirect_uri param use an endpoint to handle all the logic related to LinkedIn.

Step 2: When the user finishes login in, Linkedin is going to send a GET request to that endpoint, this request will have an "Authorization Token", this token is just a temporal token and it won't allow you to get your user's data.

Step 3: Use the Authorization Token you just received and send a post request to Linkedin

Step 4: Linkedin will send you back an Access Token (this is the one you are looking for), now you can request all the information you want

Step 5: Redirect your user back to your web app.

The structure of the request as well of the anchor tag params are available here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I'm trying to avoid redirecting the user to another page. I already have an Oauth2 flow working for LinkedIn  where I receive the code in the server and use it to retrieve the access token. In some cases, though, I want the user to do the login without redirecting to another page, that is why I wanted to use the JS SDK instead of the Oauth2 flow.

Comment: Right after posting this answer, I fixed the redirection bit in my application, I'm opening the linkedin's login form in a new window and when the whole process is done I send the data to the main window.